# Library for Audio files

Tags: 12.04, sound, c, matlab

I have written a project in  Matlab, using some signal processing (fft,convolution,PSD etc), and I have to put it on ubuntu  , for that I need to write a project in C, and I was wondering if there   is a library that can help me to do those taks in Ubuntu or in linux in general .

thanks in advance for any hint !